# MySQL Lock alternative in Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle11g

I am migrating an application which was earlier using MySQL. The application has now to be developed using Oracle. 
I did not find any alternative for

```
 $lock = $conn->execute('SELECT IS_FREE_LOCK("' . $lock_key . '")');
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use user-defined locks, you'd need to use the [`dbms_lock` package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lock.htm).  It would be *very*, *very* unusual, though, to want to use user-defined locks in an Oracle application.  It is very unusual that the locking that Oracle provides automatically would be insufficient.

If you do go down the path of user-defined locks, `dbms_lock.request` acquires the lock.  The only way to determine whether the lock is "free" is to request it in the appropriate mode and to check the return value.  You can specify a relatively short timeout if you want to avoid blocking too long.

Comment: Thanks Justin. But the application, at various points checks for the user-defined locks and writes file accordingly. So, I did google but could not find a way out to set a user-defined lock. This is my first application with oracle database and I might be finding various issues down the line as I go ahead. I will go through the dbms_lock section.